# WP8 - DatePicker - Lock month and Year

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, datepicker

I would like to know if it's possible to use the DatePicker Control from [Windows Phone Toolkit](http://phone.codeplex.com/) without giving users the possibility to change month and year, only days.

I haven't find any function or parameters who can be used to do it. Maybe a custom template ? 
I did not found any sample of someone doing something like that.

If someone can share informations, thx

Comment: This may help http://netprogrammingodyssey.wordpress.com/2010/11/14/monthyear-only-datepicker/

Comment: What don't you programmatically set the month and year, and just create a custom picker containing only the days ?